# Decrease length of array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function, numbers

1. I create an array of random and unique numbers from 1 to 51 //[0,1,2,3,4...,51]
2. i want to take 5 random numbers from that array EXAMPLE //[3,5,27,31,44]
3. Now i wont to delete that numbers from the principal array so the decrease of array decrease of 5

This is the code i created is:

```
const filterRandomValue = function (deck) {
          const randomNumbers = deck
            .sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random())
            .slice(0, 5);
        
          return deck.filter((val) => !randomNumbers.includes(val));
        };
    

filterRandomValue(randomUniqueNum(51, 51)) // it returns an array of 46 elements and just for one times it works
```

I create a button and each time i click it, i wont to decrease the numbers until it will reach a number at least equal of 5 or >= 5, and i don't know how to do it.

Because if i run the functions again it will create a full (51 elements) array.

Anyone can help me??

Comment: `1 to 51 //[0,1,2,3,4...,51]`   How come you have a 0 then?, also if your array size is 51, and you pick 51 unique numbers from 1-51, then your basically saying every number from 1 to 51, IOW: the numbers are not random.

Comment: @Keith Your criticisms are valid, but to the best of my understanding they have an array `[0 : 51]` and want to select 5 random numbers from that array, and remove those numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be fixed by separating the creation from the editing. Create the array and store it in a block variable. Then you can access that array in your function everytime the button is clicked.

```js
const filterRandomValue = function(deck) {
  const randomNumbers = deck.sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random()).slice(0, 5);
  return deck.filter((val) => !randomNumbers.includes(val)).sort( (a,b) => +a - +b);
};

const randomUniqueNum = () => {
  let x = 0,
    d = [];
  while (++x < 51) d.push(x)
  return d
}
let array = randomUniqueNum()

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
document.querySelector('.extract').addEventListener('click', () => {
    array = filterRandomValue(array)
    display()
  })
  display()
})

const display = () => {
document.querySelector('.numbers').innerText = array.join(', ')
document.querySelector('.n').innerText = array.length
}
```

```css
.numbers{
width:400px;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class='numbers'></textarea>
<p>#array items: <span class='n'></span>
  <button class='extract'>extract</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting `randomUniqueNum` straight into your `filterRandomValue` function, try creating an array with `randomUniqueNum` and then using that.

```
let myArr = randomUniqueNum(51, 51)
  .sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random())
  .slice(0, 5);
filterRandomValue(myArr); // array length: 46
filterRandomValue(myArr); // array length: 41
```

The error is that you are generating a new array each time you call `randomUniqueNum`.

---

Though your question is now answered, I think there are some fundamental problems with your code.

The `randomUniqueNum` function is pointless if you're using 51 unique numbers in a length 51 array. By that logic, the array is just the numbers 1 to 51, or 0 to 50, depending on where you start.

I think you should take a look at the steps you're taking and work out what parts are necessary.